# Как сделать сквозную нумерацию для нескольких списков в HTML?

Tags: html, css

Хочу получить что-то типа

какой-то контент

1. раз
2. два

какой-то контент

3. три
4. четыре

Но при этом использовать просто несколько ol с li, превентивно не прописывая номера для каждого li

Answer (score 3):

Есть специальный атрибут `start`:

```html
<p>какой-то контент</p>
<ol>
    <li>раз</li>
    <li>два</li>
</ol>
<p>какой-то контент</p>
<ol start="3">
    <li>три</li>
    <li>четыре</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Ухтышка прям...

Comment: Минус в том, что надо ручками считать, а считать ручками больше десяти мы не умеем =-(

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант задать для body или какого-то контейнера счётчик, увеличивать его на каждом li, а в content для ol > li::marker прописать подставление значения счётчика, но, возможно, есть что-то более красивое

```
<style>
body {
    counter-reset: item 0;
}
ol > li::marker {
    content: counter(item) '. ';
}
li {
    counter-increment: item;
}
</style>
```